# The best way to load javascript locally if web not available?

Tags: jquery

I am using the following. The intent is that it will load jQuery even if I am running on my development machine and the internet is not available.

Can someone let me know if this is the best way to do this?

```
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="/Scripts/jquery/jquery-1.6.1.min.js">\x3C/script>')
```

Thanks

Comment: you can just download the jQuery library and include it in your script. Of course the path is relative to the script.

Comment: I understand this. However is downloading the best way to go. Does nobody use the googleapis?

Comment: yep, because when you include it in you files your script wont load it anymore from google.Loading it locally saves time to execute scripts. You wont notice this for small sites. But if you got a large site you can see the difference.

Answer (score 0):

You should always use a relative path, and deploy "jquery-1.6.1.min.js" with your web app. This way, you won't be dependant on "ajax.googleapis.com" availability.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can download the jquery and put it to your local mechine 
[Download jquery](http://blog.jquery.com/2011/05/12/jquery-1-6-1-released/)

Comment: Sorry but I think you missed the point of the question. I understand I can download jQuery. But is that the best place for it ?

Answer (score 0):

@ Richard A,

The 'point' of the googleapis is the assumption that they are widely used and therefore when someone visits your site then there is a very real possibility that they already have jquery from the googleapi in their browser cache. This results in them not having to download it and hence speeding up your sites loading time.